# Sending EXTRA_REFERRER to google play

Tags: android, google-play

The usecase is following:
I have an android app, i click on an item int the app and launch an external app if that app is installed.
If not i open google play from an intent and want to send the name of my app as referrer to the app  i want to install.
I have following code but it doesn't seems to work

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?c=apps&q=" + searchString));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER_NAME,  Uri.parse("android-app://" + getContext().getPackageName()));

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER,  Uri.parse("android-app://" + getContext().getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

but it doesn't seems to work.
According to the app-writer they handle the referrer name on their side.
Do i need to add something extra in the AndroidManifest.xml or i am doing everything wrong?

Comment: Do you want your app install through a referrer code from your another app ?

Comment: What i want is to send the name of my already installed app to the app i want to install.

Comment: But the app which you want to install is yours or 3rd party ?

Comment: 3d party. But according to them they have code to handle it in their side

Answer (score 0):

I think EXTRA_REFERRER_NAME takes a String rather than a URI as the value https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REFERRER_NAME

But I have never tried this with Play